# Rxjs - Can't convert cold observable into a hot one

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

So I am using Angular 2 and struggling to make an HTTP request observable to be shared across multiple observers. More specifically I would like to share the all the response types, including errors.

I've tried like that:

```
return this._http.request(new Request(options))
  .map((res: Response) => this.refreshToken(res))
  .share()
```

and then

```
this.data.request()
  .map((response: Response) => (new financeiro.FetchCompletedAction(response)))
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.log('lancamento-effects:');
    return Observable.of(new feedback.HttpRequestFailedAction(["Erro ao inserir lançamento"]))
  })
```

this code above is suposed to send an error action that ultimately shows an error message on the user screen.

Actually this is happening twice..

[image]

Also it gets printed twice on console.

[image]

Comment: Hey. It's not clear how your code is organized. Your first block of code shows the body of the `this.data.request()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code ([Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oCZg3yqxtCaNAybvioRl?p=preview)):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="subscribe()">Subscribe</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  obs: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    // Create the observable ONCE + Share.
    this.obs = this.http.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
      .do(() => console.log('***SIDE EFFECT***'))
      .mapTo('***RESULT***')
      .share();
  }

  subscribe() {
    // Subscribe to the same observable TWICE.
    this.obs.subscribe(val => console.log('subs1', val));
    this.obs.subscribe(val => console.log('subs2', val));
  }
}
```

Here's what the console shows:

```
***SIDE EFFECT***
subs1 ***RESULT***
subs2 ***RESULT***
```

One side-effect (i.e. HTTP request), two subscriptions.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `share()` not working in my code. Do we need import operators for share?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every subscriber subscribes to the *same* hot observable. Every time you call:

```
return this._http.request(new Request(options))
  .map((res: Response) => this.refreshToken(res))
  .share()
```

You are creating a new hot observable from a cold observable.

Example assuming the above code is wrapped in a function called foo(): If you do the following, you will create 2 hot observables and 2 http requests:

```
foo().subscribe(...)
foo().subscribe(...)
```

Whereas the following will only create a single hot observable (and single http request):

```
let hotObs = foo();
hotObs.subscribe(...)
hotObs.subscribe(...);
```